# Where does dm crypt keeps crypt list?

Tags: server, kernel, 14.04, application-development, encryption

If we enable encryption via cryptsetup tool on linux. Where does it keeps the crypt list/ encryption disk sector information etc ? Is it resides inside the LUKS header or device mapper kernel itself would takes care all of those information?

Thanks for your reply.

~
Abhrajyoti

Answer (score 0):

During the initial setup `cryptsetup luksFormat`, some information, including the auto-generated master key of your encrypted volume, and various other information on what type of encryption is used, is stored in the LUKS header on your encrypted partition. This information can be viewed using

`cryptsetup luksDump $blockdev`.

This is persistent, as it is stored as part of the encrypted volume.

When you decrypt an encrypted LUKS volume `cryptsetup luksOpen`, your passphrase or keyfile is used to unlock one of the 8 key slots present in the header to get to your master key. A device mapper virtual block device is created referencing the encrypted block device, with the master key and other encryption details gotten from the LUKS header.

This typically looks like `/dev/mapper/decryptedvolumename`.

A device-mapper block device is ephemeral -- it only lasts as long as you don't shut down the machine, very much like a typical mount.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.</br> As i know cryptsetup is destructive in nature i.e. it would delete all the existing data from the partition. Is there any way to make encryption keeping the existing data. If yes exactly what all module do i need to implement? Though i would like to use device mapper at the backend for encryption support. I don't mind to avoid cryptsetup tool if possible. Any comment/suggestion?

Comment: There isn't a way, short of backing up the partition before hand. Cryptsetup isn't magic. It has to store the encrypted data somewhere, and that's on the partition you specify.